# WCF DataServices Service Operation Parameter - Character Replacement

Tags: wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0, service-operations

I've a very strange problem (using SL5, WCF DataServices 5.0.1):
I've a ServiceOperation with 2 String parameters (Username, Password) which checks if the users exists

```
public IQueryable<User> Login(string username, string password)
{...}
```

When I try to call this everythings works fine, except the case that the password-hash contains a '+' character in it. In this case, it seems if it is replaced by a whitespace-character:

```
var pwd = CRQWKrKzCcQVnlhk2zl0j5QM+c5ujQGMv0XXnh4genI=
this.Context.BeginExecute<User>(new Uri(string.Format("/Login?username='{0}'&password='{1}'", username, pwd), UriKind.Relative), (ar) => { .. }, null);
```

If I grab that with Fiddler, the Request-Header seems ok to me...

```
GET /Service.svc/Login?username='xyz'&password='CRQWKrKzCcQVnlhk2zl0j5QM+c5ujQGMv0XXnh4genI=' HTTP/1.1
```

But in the WebForms-Tab the Password-QueryString already has a whitespace instead of the '+'. Same result if I debug that on the Server...

Does anyone of you know why the '+' is replaced? 
Are there other invalid characters? 
How can I avoid that?

**Update/EDIT :**

Surprisingly the following query works as expected:

```
var query = (DataServiceQuery<User>) from c in this.Context.Users
                                             where
                                                 c.Username.Equals(username.ToLower()) &&
                                                 c.Password.Equals(Cryptography.ComputeSha256Hash(password + username.ToLower())) 
                                             select c;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried encoding the URL before executing it? I believe both + and = can be encoded, and I don't think the call to `Execute` has any logic to automatically attempt encoding.

Comment: I thought that a String in .NET is always Unicode (UTF16)? Nevertheless I tried a fix password like 'Test+123' which results in the same mystery. BUT I tried the following which suprisingly worked (see the Updated Secion in my Question)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Stafford for the Hint.
I've now a solution for this problem:

```
var pwd = Uri.EscapeDataString(Cryptography.ComputeSha256Hash(password + username.ToLower()));
```

The Query will now look like this:

```
/GET Service.svc/Login?username='xyz'&password='CRQWKrKzCcQVnlhk2zl0j5QM%252Bc5ujQGMv0XXnh4genI%253D'
```

And on the Server the equivalent unsecaping:

```
var pwd = Uri.UnescapeDataString(password);
```

See http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/08/10/Use-EscapeUriString-instead-of-UrlEncode-for-Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The query string portion of the URL needs to be encoded properly. Calls to the WCF DS client LINQ provider (e.g., `context.Users.Where(...)`) are automatically encoded by the client-side stack. Calls to `context.Execute` do not modify the URL in this manner, so the values there will need to be encoded by other code.

Try this in Visual Studio to see the difference:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using System.Linq;

namespace Scratch
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/"));
            var query1 = context.CreateQuery<Category>("Categories").Where(c => c.Name == "abcd+efgh=ijlk");
            var query2 = context.Execute<Category>(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories()?$filter=Name eq 'abcd+efgh=ijlk'"));
            Console.WriteLine("context.Categories.Where(...): {0}", query1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("context.Execute<Category>(...): {0}", ((QueryOperationResponse)query2).Query.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```